# How to solve something like $x^2 + \sqrt{2}\,x - 3$?

Tags: quadratics

What is exactly the MO when it comes to solving a quadratic equation like $x^2 + \sqrt{2}\,x - 3$? Do I take the part with the under root to the other side and end up with $x^4$?

Comment: Do you mean $ x^2 + \sqrt{2}x - 3=0$? Otherwise it is not an equation and there is nothing to solve.

Comment: Is the second term $x\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{2x}$?

Comment: 1) You have not answered the question of @John  2) You have to place an $=0$ 3) Thank you, I have learned a new acronym MO (modus operandi) but  why not the good old "method"...

Comment: IconrrigiblePenguin A clarification would be nice.

Comment: If it is a quadratic, then the middle term should be interpreted as $\sqrt{2}\,x$ and not as $\sqrt{2x}$.

Answer (score -1):

If you are solving $x^2+x\sqrt 2-3=0$ the quadratic formula works just fine.  You get $$x=\frac 12\left(-\sqrt 2\pm\sqrt{2+12}\right)=\frac 12(\pm\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 2)$$
The fact that there is a square root on the linear term is not an issue.